# Problems on Pythagorean triangle - sides in arithmetic (geometric) progression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, pythagorean-triples, geometric-progressions

> Show that there is one (no) Pythagorean triangle whose sides are in arithmetic (geometric) progression.

The problem has two parts. There is one Pythagorean triangle whose sides are in arithmetic progression. There is no Pythagorean triangle whose sides are in geometric progression.

I know that

A triplet of positive integers x, y, z satisfying the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is called Pythagorean triplet. If $x$, $y$, $z$ are Pythagorean triplet, then $x$, $y$, $z$ are pairwise prime to each other.

I don't know whether Pythagorean triplet and Pythagorean triangle are same.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: $3,4,5$ satisfies the first part.

Comment: @math131, Wiki: "A right triangle whose sides form a Pythagorean triple is called a Pythagorean triangle."

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for the defn. Please solve the remaining part of the problem: the no of PT.

Answer (score 3):

If the sides are in arithmetic progression, WLOG we can choose the sides to be $a-d,a,a+d$  where $a,a-d>0\iff a>d$

So, $(a-d)^2+a^2=(a+d)^2\iff a^2=(a+d)^2-(a-d)^2=4ad$

$\iff a(a-4d)=0\implies a=4d$ as $a\ne0$

For Geometric Progression, let the sides be $a,ak,ak^2$ where $a>0,k\ge1$

So, $a^2+(ak)^2=(ak^2)^2\implies k^4-k^2-1=0$ as $a\ne0$

$\implies k^2=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}2\implies k^2=\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}2$ as $k^2>1$

Comment: Its OK. But how to get the number of Pythagorean triangle(s)?

Comment: @math131,I think the question meant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePythagoreanTriple.html. Then the number in each case is exactly one. Else, $4d-d,4d,d+4d$ always are Pythagorean triplets whose sides are in Arithmetic Progression

Comment: Just a curious fact: the least angle $\alpha$ of the triangle with sides in geometric progression is the solution of: $\cos\alpha=\tan\alpha$

Comment: @N.S., Please disclose what is  "the first part" here?

Comment: @N.S. "$a=4d$" and "$(3k,4k,5k)$" give the exact same solutions...

Comment: For the second part (about geometric progression), it might be worth adding that $x^4-x^2-1$ has no *rational* roots by [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Hence there is no solution in positive integers.

Comment: @MartinSleziak,   Thanks! Icing on the Cake

Answer (score 1):

**For the first part** If $x,y,z$ are in arithmetic progression, then 
$$2y=x+z$$
or the same with $x,y$ interchanged.

Then 
$$x^2+y^2=z^2 \Rightarrow \\y^2=z^2-x^2=(z-x)(z+x)=(z-x)2y$$

This gives
$$x+z=2y \\
z-x=\frac{y}{2}$$

This gives $x=\frac{3y}{4}$ and $z=\frac{5y}{4}$. Deduce that $4|y$ and the writing $y=4k$ you get the arithmetic progression $(3k,4k,5k)$ is the general solution.

**For geometric**, same ides:
$$ y^2=xz \Rightarrow x^2+xz-z^2=0$$

You can either solve the quadratic in $x/z$ or if you write $d=gcd(x,z)$ and write $x=dx', z=dz'$ with gcd $(x',z')=1$ you get 
$$x'^2+x'z'-z'^2=0$$

This implies $x'|z'^2$ and $z'|x'^2$ which combined with $gcd(x',z')=1$ yields $x'=z'=1$, which is not possible.

Comment: @ labbhattacharjee, @N.S.For the first case, the general solution is  $(3k, 4k, 5k)$. I understand it. But how it can be conclude that their is one  Pythagorean triangle. For different integer value of k in  $(3k, 4k, 5k)$, one can get different triplets. Please suggest.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  Please suggest.

Comment: Please suggest at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

An approach from the other side.

Any Pythagorean triple can be generated from two non zero integers $m,n$ by:
$$
a=m^2-n^2 \qquad b=2mn \qquad c=m^2+n^2
$$

For an arithmetic progression we need:
$$
b-a=2mn-m^2+n^2=m^2+n^2-2mn=c-b 
$$
and solving we find $2n=m$ so that all such triple have the form 
$$
a=3n \qquad b=4n \qquad c=5n
$$

For a geometric progression we have:
$$
\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{2mn}{m^2-n^2}=\dfrac{m^2+n^2}{2mn}=\dfrac{c}{b}
$$
that become $m^4-4m^2n^2-n^4=0$ and have no integer solutions since $\Delta'=n^4\sqrt{5}$

Comment: a=3n, b=4n, c=5n gives infinite no of triplet for different values of n, then how the no of Pyth Trian is one?

Comment: Here the primitive Pythagorean trople is $3,4,5$ and all the other are propotional triples. Any primitive triple generates an infinite number of proportional triples. So, if we search primitve triples we have find only one .

Comment: "There is one Pythagorean triangle" means "There is one primitive Pythagorean trople" i.e "Pythagorean triangle" means "primitive Pythagorean trople"? If so, then I understand.

Comment: It is a matter of definition. If we identify all similar Pythagorean triangles than each of these correspond to one primitive triple.

Answer (score 0):

Pythagorean triplet and Pythagorean triangle are the same thing. If $GCD(A,B,C)=1$, it is called a primitive, otherwise it is called a non-primitive or multiple.

As for arithmetic progressions, there is only one triple $(3,4,5)$ where  A,B,C are consecutive numbers.  There are sequences of triples ... where $C-B=1$, where $C-A=2$, and where $B-A=\pm1$.

For $\quad C-B=1,\qquad A=2n+1\quad B=2n(n+1)\quad C=2n(n+1)+1\quad$ which produces
$(3,4,5)\quad (5,12,13)\quad (7,24,25)\quad (9,40,41)\quad (11,60,61)\quad (13,84,85)\quad (15,112,113)\quad ...$

You may notice, in the sequence above that each difference $(B-A)\in\{1,7,17,31,49,71,97\}$ which are prime numbers taken to non-negative powers where $(B-A)=\pm1\mod 8$.

For $\quad C-A=2\qquad A=4n^2-1\quad B=4n\quad C=4n^2+1\quad$ which produces
$(3,4,5)\quad (15,8,17\quad (35,12,37\quad (63,16,65)\quad (99,20,101)\quad (143,24,145)\quad (195,28,197)\quad ...$

The last one is from  my work using Euclid's formula where here, I represent it as $F(m,k)\qquad A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2. \quad$ It involves the generation of Pell numbers using a formula I developed for $m$ in terms of $k$ where $\quad m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}.\quad $ Starting with $1$, each value of $m$ is the input to the next iteration of the formula.

$$k=1\implies m=1+\sqrt{2-1}=1+1=2\qquad F(2,1)=(3,4,5)$$
$$k=2\implies m=2+\sqrt{8+1}=2+3=5\qquad F(5,2)=(21,20,29)$$
$$k=5\implies m=5+\sqrt{50-1}=5+7=12\qquad F(12,5)=(119,120,169)$$
$$k=12\implies m=12+\sqrt{288+1}=12+17=29\qquad F(29,12)=(697,696,985)$$

I don't know if any of this meets your needs but I hope you find the patterns "interesting".