# geometric progression and pythagorian triples

Tags: pythagorean-triples, geometric-progressions

3 numbers are pythagoreaan triples and also consecutive numbers of a geometric progression.Can you help me find the numbers and the report of the sides with the hypotenuse?
Thank you

Comment: well since the numbers are pythagorian triples then x^2 +y^2=z^2 and also x×q =y ; y×q =z since it is a geometric progression and q is the costant number then y/x=z/y so y^2=z×x

Comment: See also: [Problems on Pythagorean triangle - sides in arithmetic (geometric) progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342242).

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $a, ar, ar^2$ are three consecutive terms in a geometric progression. Since they are a Pythagorean triple, by the Pythagorean Theorem, assuming $r>1$,
$$a^2+(ar)^2=(ar^2)^2.$$
Dividing both sides by $a^2$ gives
$$1+r^2=r^4.$$
This is a quadratic in $r^2$ which you can use this to find $r$. You can choose any $a>0$.

Comment: actually i have already done this but i couldnt go any further

Comment: @LedjaNushi What did you find $r$ to be? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: r^4-r^2=1 and so r = +/-( sqrt2 + 2 sqrt) 5 /2 and after this i couldnt solve anything to copmlete the conditions given

Comment: Choose $r$ to be the positive root, i.e. $r=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$. Choose, say $a=1$. Then $1, r, r^2$ is your triple.

Comment: i understand but the numbers are not  supposted to be  decimal numbers

Comment: If you want the numbers to be integers, that's not possible, since we need $a$ to be an integer, and there is no integer such that $a\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ is an integer.

Comment: This is because $\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ is irrational.

Comment: ok i will try and solve it once more .if i dont solve it i guess i will ask for help again .anyways thanks

Comment: There are no solutions where all three numbers are integers.